# How to improve wifi reception on LR1110 Chip?

Tags: pcb-design, routing, ground-plane, pcb-antenna

I am building a custom PCB with the LR1110 LoRa chip, which uses a WiFi chip antenna for obtaining MAC address of the wifi networks. For the WiFi Chip antenna, I am using a W3006 Ceramic Chip Antenna.The schematic was copied from the LR1110 Development Board. This is the PCB schematic for the same: [image: Wifi Schematic]

The problem is that in the PCB layout I left a higher ground clearance than what was recommended in the datasheet(See image).
[image: Ant-1 is WiFi, Ant-2 is GNSS]

When testing the board, the PCB is only able to detect the Wifi MAC address around 1/50 times it sniffs for one. I wanted to know whether it is due to bad WiFi antenna Layout or due to any other design problems.

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT: Yeah apparently the PCB works just fine. I had just forgot to configure the wifi router to broadcast in WiFi-b frequency. Thanks a lot for the help everyone!

Comment: I don't see L7 or ANT1 in your schematic.

Comment: The schematic is only for the wifi antenna. ANT1 and L7 are the part of the GNSS antenna

Comment: you mean a BSSID when you say "MAC address", right? The terminology is a bit different between Ethernet (which has MAC addresses) and Wifi, because the BSSID describes the network, not the device. I ask because there's a difference, as far as I can remember, between these two different numbers in terms of what you can detect without access to the cryptographic secrets of an encrypted network

Comment: Either way, for how long have you been listening when you say "it sniffs for one"?